# Автоматическая обработка данных от телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

подскажите пожалуйста, имеется телеграм-бот, после нажатия на кнопку, присылающий фото. Можно ли в автоматическом режиме "нажимать на кнопку" и  сохранять id фотографий, приходящих от бота. Другого бота для этого, судя по всему, нельзя использовать из-за https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого используется клиент-апи телеграма, например pyrogram или telethon, тогда вы привяжете код к телеграм аккаунту, и программно будут доступны все функции, которые доступны вам, как пользователю телеграма.